# equation in a table LaTeX

Tags: tables, equations

I am trying to input this

```
    OneOf            & \left\{ x_{1}, \dots ,\right x_{n} \}& ~ \\
```

into one of my table rows. Because its a equation it does not like it and because I am a beginner I do not know where to include the $'s. Could someone kindly implement these into the equation for me?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example, with a full code?

Answer (score 1):

Try (based on guessing about your table):

```
    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
 OneOf  & $\left\{ x_1, \dots , x_n \right\}$   & ~     \\
    \end{tabular}
```

You can see, that the equation is start with `$` end with `$`. Of course, the equation/math term should be correct typed (you have spurious `\right` in your math term).

Hope this will help.